# Conditions for convergence over coefficients of the IVP

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I've been trying to solve this problem for sometime now, and I think I lack of tools for solving it,

**Problem:**

Let $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$, and let $\dot x = \begin{bmatrix}
    a&1 \\
    b& -a\\
 \end{bmatrix}x$, $x(0)= \begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    c\\\end{bmatrix}$.

I want to find the values for $a,b,c$ such that the solution is bounded for all $t \geq 0$.

I have no idea how to proceed more than just try to calculate the exponential matrix, cause the criterion I know for showing that the solutions are bounded is to prove that the $x(0)$ belongs to the eigenspace of the eigenvalues with nonegative real part, but that doesnt seems to work in this case. And as far as I know this seems to be a very standard problem, so if you could give me some techniques or any suggestion I would really appreciate it.

Comment: What is $t$? Do you want $x(n+1) = X \times x(n)$?

Comment: Sry I think I dont understand your question, you mean the variable $t$? Well, the solution of the IVP should be something like $x(t)=\Pi(t)x_{0}$

Comment: Do you know what to explicitly solve the system when $a, b, c$ are given constants? (That is, to find $II(t)$?)

Comment: Yes(I think), the exponential matrix right? Cause I tried calculating the eigenvalues which are $\pm\sqrt{a^{2}+b}$. Then we calculate the $e^{tA}=\Pi(t) $ in the constant case. But I think this does not work here.

Comment: Please add further insights by [editing](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3469046/edit) the question. Then answers can reply to it, comments are considered ephemere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You found that the eigenvalues of the system matrix are $\pm\sqrt{a^2+b}$. If these are real, you get exponential solutions, one basis solution increasing. You would have to check if you can set the coefficient of this growing part to zero in the solution formula for one of the admissible initial conditions.

The same if you have a double eigenvalue zero, $b=-a^2$, the general solution is linear, so check if you can set the linear coefficient to zero.

In the case $a^2+b<0$, both eigenvalues are imaginary, the solution is a periodic oscillation which is always bounded.